# How to import products in a store view?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I have a csv file for french store view. But when i import that csv file, it overrides the default store view data. How to resolve that problem?
Here is the structure of csv file.

> sku|name|description|short_description|_store

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.
1-Go to `system->import/export->Dataflow-Profiles` and then add new profile. Here you will specify your store in which you want to add data.
2-Upload your csv file under "Upload file" tab.
3-Go to "run profile" tab and run it.
Done!